# TypeError Joi.validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, node-modules, joi

[image: look]

please help with that i am not sure what is happening im using the following:

```
"body-parser": "1.19.0",
"express": "4.17.1",
"joi": "17.1.1"
```

but it is only the joi that im having issues with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `schema.validate` instead of `Joi.validate`

Reference: https://joi.dev/api#example

Answer (score 0):

Joi changed in implementation. You should be validating the schema against your request body.
It should be something like `schema.validate(req.body, (err, result) => {} .....)`

Answer (score -3):

Did you do :

```
const Joi = require('joi')
```

at beginning of this file? Notice the capital J.